# apply css after reload page

Tags: jquery, css

I am in a web page:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

In this page I have a link:

```
<a href="/dynamic-username/boards">user's boards</a>
```

in this page I doing click in above link and I go to this page:

```
http://localhost:3000/dynamic-username/boards
```

Dynamic username is the username for each user.

I want to apply a css style to the link, if I am visiting this last page. If I visit this page of any user.

**How can I apply the css style after I go to second page?**

This link is shared for every views in my framework and I have the same css for all views.

I want that if detect this url apply to this link a style css with

```
font-weight:bold
```

Comment: add <link rel="stylesheet" href="/url/style.css"> to the <head> of the document?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please re-vise?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem better. I am sorry but unable to understand what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're after is the [:visited pseudo selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3avisited) of the link:

```
 /* Unvisited links will be normal font weight */
 a:link{
   font-weight: normal;
 }

 /* Link will be bold after user has visited it */
 a:visited{
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

This will change the appearance of any links on the user's board page that you've already been to.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second stylesheet or inline style on the destination page that will override the styles for that link. No javascript necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the url and compare to href of the link with javascript but it would be cleaner to simply add a "current_page" class in your server code and generate a css rule for that link class